# Emotion css hover over parent and target inner element

Tags: css, reactjs, emotion

I have the following code using [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction):

```
const styles = {
  container: css({
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#282c34",
    padding: "20px",
    color: "#fff",
    "&:hover .inner": {
      backgroundColor: "blue",
    },
  }),
  inner: css({
    margin: "auto",
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    padding: "20px",
    color: "black",
  }),
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div css={styles.container}>
      <div css={styles.inner} className="inner">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to change the inner element styles when I hover over the parent container. At the moment, I have to give it a `className` and target it like this:

```
"&:hover .inner": {
  backgroundColor: "blue",
}
```

Is there a better way with Emotion where I don't have to manually give it a className?

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/peaceful-shaw-forked-3tt68h

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML here instead of a code sandbox link and the reactjs? I'm not sure how react would handle this, but does `&:hover > div` or `&:hover div` not work?

Comment: That would work, but this is just an example. Imagine I have a lot more nested divs, that approach wouldn't work. Will need a way to target a specific element.

Comment: You need to add that information to the question. As of now, you'd get the exact answer I gave. If you need to target further nested elements, you'd definitely need a class or some identifier.

Comment: Usually css-in-js libraries have a way to do this. I'm wondering if there's a way to do it in Emotion. Eg: for styled-components they have a way to refer to another component like this: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components